# parsing nested json and save in csv

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have a json file look like

```
"persons" : {
    "-L1oNCxcRtS1" : {
      "createdByUser" : "P94r8Wlv3lOUZwsKB",
      "createdOn" : "2018-01-02T00:58:55.082Z",
      "modifiedByUser" : "P94r8Wlv3lOUZwsKBeb",
      "modifiedOn" : "2018-01-02T00:58:55.082Z",
      "photoBlobUser" : "OUZwsKBeblAy4vEyQ2",
      "userId" : "wsKBeblAy4vEyQ2"
    },
    "-L1oNKHP3C" : {
      "createdByUser" : "UblFOHN3BqRKr2",
      "createdOn" : "2018-01-02T00:59:29.641Z",
      "emailAddress" : "adabas@abc.in",
      "isSocialDataShared" : true,
      "modifiedByUser" : "4owBjUblFOHN3BqRKr2",
      "modifiedOn" : "2018-04-11T16:00:08.318Z",
      "name" : "Arun",
      "nickname" : "Arun",
      "photoBlobUserID" : "4owBjHYyehdMwwUbl",
      "userId" : "4owBjHYyehdMwwUblFOHN3BqRKr2"
    }
.............
```

where -L1oNCxcRtS1 and -L1oNKHP3C are persons, we need to parse the structure like it and save it in csv like table format where one additional column will be persons with the two values and rest of the columns will be keys.

Please suggest.

Comment: what have you done so far ? show your work.

Answer (score 0):

Python has a library as 'Json' for parsing json data. You can parse the json format data using json.dumps() method and it will return you a dictionary with key, value pairs. From there you can very much separate the respective key, values.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html